# How do I select only top level folders using CrossListQueryCache?

Tags: search, caml-query, spquery, crosslistqueryinfo

I want to select the list of folders (without subfolders, not recursive) of a Document library using CrossListQueryCache.

Everything is working fine except that i am receiving ALL the folders and subfolders in the list and not just the first level of folders. what do i need to change in the code below so that only the first level of folders is returned without their subfolders and sub-subfolders etc...

```
string query = string.Empty; 
string websQuery = string.Format("<Webs Scope=\"{0}\"/>", "None"); 
string lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\"" + " ><List ID=\"" + listid + "\" /></Lists>";   
bool useList = true; 
string relativeUrl = this.GetRelativeUrl(); 
query = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='LookUp'>1</Value></Eq></Where>", relativeUrl);   
CrossListQueryInfo info = new CrossListQueryInfo(); 
info.Lists = lists; 
info.Webs = websQuery; 
info.Query = query; 
info.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>"; 
info.WebUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl; 
CrossListQueryCache cache = new CrossListQueryCache(info); 
SiteDataResults sd = cache.GetSiteDataResults(site, true);
```

Comment: Even after FileDirRef and the List Name it din't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see a way you can do this...not with a CrossListQuery anyway.  If you were doing this against a single list (i.e. SPList.GetItems(SPQuery) then you could add:

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>"ListName"</Value></Eq>
```

and that would pull back only the top level folders, as the folders under that would have a FileDirRef of "ListName\TopLevelFolder" and so on.

Comment: Yeah, just don't include `Scope="Recursive"` like you normally would.